# additive white Gaussian noise -ask fsk psk

Tags: matlab, noise, gaussian, bpsk

i want to simulate a system that uses ask,fsk ,psk in Matlab with additive Gaussian noise for each mode . figure shows the system propti [image: proprietie] and Eb/N0=6db my question is  how to calculate the standard variation of the Gaussian noise for each mode , i tried the following :

- EbN0dB=6;
- EbN0=10^(EbN0dB/10);% db to linear scale
- EN0=1/(EbN0);
- sigmaASk=sqrt(N0);% siqma for bask
- siqmaPsk=sqrt(2*N0);% siqma for
  bask
- sigmaFsk=sqrt(N0(1-sinc(4*1000*0.001);
- mff=transmitted+sigma*randn(1,10*30);%modulated 10 bit signal plus
  noise

Comment: It's not really clear where the 6dB come from? Also, you said "you tried" these things, but what's the outcome? What's not OK about that? How can you expect to do any reasonable simulation with only 10 symbols?

Comment: eb /no is given in the question ,these 10 bits will be transmitted 10000 times for simulating purposes . my question is about the formulas used are they correct ?

Comment: we can't tell; you're not defining how many bits per symbol you put into your modulations.

Comment: 1 bit per symbol